# How can I change the desktop color to black in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, colors, desktop

I'm trying to change the desktop color to black but I can't seem to find how, other than by creating a solid black image.

In `System Preferences` -> `Desktop & Screensaver`, there are a few colors, but I can't find any way to change the desktop background color to black...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can create `~/Library/Desktop Pictures` and place anything you want in there.  The Apple-provided solid colors are simply PNGs in `/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors`.

```
mress:10242 Z$ ls /Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Solid\ Colors 
Solid Aqua Blue.png       Solid Gray Light.png      Solid Mint.png
Solid Aqua Dark Blue.png  Solid Gray Medium.png     Solid White.png
Solid Aqua Graphite.png   Solid Kelp.png
Solid Gray Dark.png       Solid Lavender.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Download:  [Solid Black](http://peelman.us/skitch/Solid%20Black.png)

Place it in `/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/`

Browser to where you were in System Prefs, Select it from the list.